# how can I select an element in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the code below, how can I find the following element in the dom?

```
<!-- START Main Navigation -->
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>    
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Layout 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- END Main Navigation -->
```

I would like to find the link That points to Home and apply the `class=active` attribute to **it's parent** `<li>`

How can I do this?

I know this is a simple question but I'm just learning jquery. Also, there are other `<li><a href="/"....` in the code so I need to incorporate the `<nav id="main-nav-list">` in the select somehow.

Lastly, I need to do this whenever I'm in Contact or blog as well.

Comment: You should probably give a more complete example of your markup. You should also probably add a `home` class or id to your `<a>`.

Comment: Added a lot more details :) thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#main-nav-list a').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text() == 'Home') $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cRRR5/)**

Comment: @nerdarama - How does it not work? OP said "I would like to find the Home link and apply the class=active attribute to it's parent `<li>`" which is exactly what this does.

Comment: This is kind of clumsy, I'd rather `$('#main-nav-list a').filter(function () { return $(this).text() == "Home" }).parent().addClass("active");`

Comment: @meager - essentially the code is the same. I considered adding a filter example but there was really no difference.

Comment: I tried this and its not working for me here's what I have:
`<script type="text/javascript"> $('#main-nav a').each(function () { if ($(this).text() == 'Contact') $(this).parent().addClass('active'); });</script>`

Comment: @hjavaher  It's working try to put your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {` handler..

Comment: @Justin, thanks that worked. My understanding (and I don't know why and where I read that) was that $() was equivalent to $(document).ready.... I guess, I have to start learning JQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-nav a').each(function () {
        if($(this).html()=='Home'){
            $(this).parent().attr('class','active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$('#main-nav-list li').first().addClass('active');
```

There are quite a few other ways but hopefully that makes sense :)

That is assuming 'Home' will always be first though.

Comment: well, the thing is though in other pages of the site I need to select for another main-nav-list that has like a "/contact" link. how would that work? Wouldn't this method set the class of all the <li> in the main-nav-list that contain a link to 'active'?

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to achieve this, but the one below looks for the 'Home' link by matching the link text:

```
$('a:contains("Home")').addClass('active');
```

Have a look at the selectors documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but will add 'active' to ALL links with 'Home', what if he had a menu option called: "Computers Home" and "Science Home" ?

Comment: @mkprogramming - yes you are right, that was the first thing I thought of while reading the OP's question :) Many ways to approach this though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#main-nav-list li > a.active').removeClass('active'); 
//First undo the current active :)

$('ul#main-nav-list li > a[href="/"]').addClass('active');  
//Then apply to the one you want
```

You can also get the current window url to search for the corresponding `a` tag by accessing the `window.location.href` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you just want to target elements having exact string "Home".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($("a"), function(index, node) {
         if($(node).html() == "Home") {
           $(node).parent("li").addClass("active");
         }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/uqT6J/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using the filter function to match the exact text in the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/aWVJg/

```
$('#main-nav-list a').filter(
function () 
{
  return this.text === 'Home';
}).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
$('ul#main-nav-list li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active')
```

Comment: `li:nth-child(1)` should be `li:first`. You're also adding the class to the `<a>`, not its parent, and you're "ading" the class instead of "adding" the class.

Answer (score -3):

```
$('myElement').addClass();
```

And not to be rude but do you know anything about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? Take a look at the home page of jQuery and they explain how to do that. The API is also very helpful.

Comment: pretty rude answer for someone who provides invalid code... like the old saying goes... don't throw rocks in a glass house